# Animating a AVPlayerLayer using UIPropertyAnimator

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, calayer

I'm trying to animate a sublayer in a UIView. The sublayer is a AVPlayerLayer. While it's easy to do in normal life to animate a CALayer, I'm having a hard time doing it when a UIPropertyAnimator drives the animation. I really want to use the UIPropertyAnimator because it's so simple to animate interactively with keyframes.

Here's a Playground that demonstrate the issue. I would expect the green CALAyer to follow it's parent blue UIView. But it goes right at the end frame of the animation and never move again.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class BlueSubview: UIView {
let subLayer: AVPlayerLayer

init() {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")! )
    subLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    super.init(frame: .zero)

    layer.addSublayer(subLayer)
    backgroundColor = .blue
    player.play()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)
    subLayer.frame = bounds
    CATransaction.commit()
}
}

class BlurDemoViewController: UIViewController {
let subview = BlueSubview()
var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(subview)
    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    subview.frame = view.bounds
    subview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // animator does all the hard work and just lets us tell it what fraction of its animation we want to see. note that duration is not important here as we will just drive the animation manually
    animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, curve: .linear) {
        self.subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    }

    // make a slider always at the bottom of view
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.frame.origin.x = 20
    slider.frame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - slider.frame.size.height - 20
    slider.frame.size.width = view.frame.size.width - 40
    slider.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin]
    slider.value = 1
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(slider)
}

// this function will be called by UISlider when its value changes. It needs @objc so that it has a #selector (which UISlider uses to send target-action events)
@objc private func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    // The green layer doesn't follow it's blue superview with the animator
    animator?.fractionComplete = CGFloat(1 - sender.value)


    // This works if I don't use the animator
    // subview.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(sender.value) * view.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(sender.value) * view.bounds.height)
}
}

// now just instantiate a blur demo vc and give it an image to show
let vc = BlurDemoViewController()
// PlaygroundSupport allows us to show a live view (controller)
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Tried using `runningPropertyAnimator` with `.layoutSubviews` passed in as options, and it did not help.. It is a property animator after all, maybe you can resort to using subviews?

Comment: Property animators are about views. Layer animation is about layers. And never the twain shall meet. The whole question makes no sense.

Comment: Are you find the solution?